# I am storing text file in a mongodb and i want to perform search operations on content of a file. Is mongodb support content search of file?

Tags: java, mongodb, full-text-search

I have created a Java Application and through it i am able to insert a file in mongodb and now want to perform a content search on it.

Here is my file insertion code.

```
import java.io.File;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFS;
import com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSDBFile;
import com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSInputFile;

public class TestFileInsert {
public static void main(String[] args){

    try{
        // To create a connection with mongodb
        MongoClient mongoclient = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
        DB db = mongoclient.getDB( "temp" );
        System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");

        // To insert a file into mongo db using grid fs
        String newFileName = "TssMessage";
        File newfile = new File("/home/n.dat");
        GridFS gfsPhoto = new GridFS(db, "Test");
        GridFSInputFile gfsFile = gfsPhoto.createFile(newfile);
        gfsFile.setFilename(newFileName);
        gfsFile.save();

        System.out.println("Text File Inserted Successfully");

        // to get a file already in database
        String getFileName = "TssMessage";
        GridFS gfsPhoto1 = new GridFS(db, "Test");
        GridFSDBFile imageForOutput = gfsPhoto1.findOne(getFileName);
        System.out.println(imageForOutput);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
    }
}
}
```

How can I perform a content search in this database?

Comment: A content search. On a photo. Or a dat file. So how is MongoDB supposed to parse that file? What you probably want is to save some [metadata](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/gridfs/#files.metadata) and create a text index over the metadata fields you want to query.

Answer (score 0):

Your files seem to be images. Content analysis of images is a very hard problem. And I mean very, very hard. There is some progress on corner applications (text recognition, biometric face recognition...) but *the* universal image identification algorithm which can recognize any image just like the human brain can is still an unsolved problem of computer science and will likely remain so for the foreseeable future. And MongoDB isn't trying to provide a solution for this sector.

But even for a much simpler case, let's say text file search, MongoDBs GridFS would not be the best tool.

When your files are text-based, you could try to create a text index on the `fs.chunks` collection, but in this collection each file is stored as multiple separate documents, each one (by default) with 255kByte of data. When the information you are searching for happens to be across the chunk boundary, this won't help you much.

However, you have the ability to query files by the metadata you store with them. Depending on what you want to do, you could extract relevant search terms from the files before you store them and store these search terms in the metadata.